# Is there in angular something similar to the JavaScript .querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I had created an inventory calculator in JavaScript that gives the count of items based on the weight. It has 4 inputs. I'd like to create the same calculator in angular. Is there a way to get an array of elements like the .querySelectorAll() does with in JavaScript, but in Angular? Below is the my code of the JavaScript.  I'd really like to know if I can accomplish the same with Angular. Here is the [link](https://inventory-calculator.joesalaz.com) to the calculator for a better Idea of what it does.

```js
let message = document.getElementById('message');
let IDs = document.getElementById('IDs')
.querySelectorAll(
  "#contrlQty, #ctrl-Wt, #massWt, #singlWt, #output, #message"
  );   

  input = () => {
     message.innerHTML = ""; //Message is Gone!
   }

calculate = () => {
if(IDs[2].value == "" && IDs[3].value == "" && isNaN(IDs[4])){
message.innerHTML = "You must enter at least a mass weight and a single object weight value";
 return false;
}

  let count = IDs[4];
   if(IDs[0].value > 0 && IDs[1].value > 0){   
     message.innerHTML = "";                         
  IDs[3].value = IDs[1].value / IDs[0].value; 
  let result = IDs[2].value / IDs[3].value;
  let n = result.toFixed(0);  
  
  count.innerHTML = n;
}

  else if(IDs[0].value == 0 && IDs[1].value == 0) 
  {
  let result = IDs[2].value / IDs[3].value;
  let n2 = result.toFixed(0);
  count.innerHTML = n2;
  }
}

 reset = () => {
     
 IDs[0].value = 0;
 IDs[1].value = "";
 IDs[2].value = "";
 IDs[3].value = "";
 IDs[4].innerHTML = 0;
          
}
```

Comment: I would use angular reactive forms. because angular has different ways of manipulating the DOM and of getting values back. so your function above can be written in many different ways that would work in angular but you will need some understanding of how angular operates

Comment: Would you mind showing a small example on how you would use anything that would accomplish something similar? If you can't, that's fine. I'd keep waiting for a more specific answer to my question.

Comment: Angular is an abstraction that makes it so you generally don't need to worry about the DOM directly like you're doing.

Comment: I will try to make a stackBlitz example using reactiveForms

Comment: I've used angular before, but it has been a while. I do have a general idea. @ Mj Jameel. That would be nice if you could show me that example. Something small. I just need some direction so that I have a better idea. I'd greatly appreciate that.

Comment: @ ggorlen I know angular works different than javascript. That's why I am asking for a small example on how to go about doing something similar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is a stackBlitz that takes an array and creates and FormArray onInit then pushes it to the dom. I also added a button that would log the values and also show them on the DOM

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dx6j6g

ill put the ts file code and the HTML just incase stackblitz decides to mess up again.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
  numberOfFields = 5;
  values = []
  inputs: FormArray;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputs  = new FormArray([])

    for(let i=0; i < this.numberOfFields; i++){
      this.inputs.push(new FormControl(null))
    }
  }

  getControl(i) {
    return this.inputs.at(i) as FormControl;
  }

  getValues() {
    this.values = [...this.inputs.value]
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="formInput" *ngFor="let input of inputs.controls; index as i">
  <input [formControl]="getControl(i)">
</div>

<button (click)="getValues()">get values</button>
<hr>

<p *ngFor="let val of values">{{val}}</p>
```

Comment: I didnt add validation or anything fancy because its outside the scope of this question but you can check https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms for more documentation on the subject

Comment: Thank you! this is a very useful response! The code is very clear to understand. Thank you for this head start! Also thank you for sharing the link to the documentaion.